# importxml in javascript function googlesheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I try to get some information from a website with IMPORTXML.

I wrote a function, it works but it's not what I want.

```
function info() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  cell.setFormula('=importXml("https://example.com&sw="&M2&"&s=on", "/html/body/div[1]/p[2]/a")');
}
```

The url and xpath are an example.
the cell M2 is an information I add in the url.

Because the first worked, I tried to write something more difficult... and I'm lost.

I search to get an information in the cell of column M to complete the url, stock the value that I get with xpath to put it in the column O.

When there is nothing in a cell of M, I want skip it and continue.

I start to do something but it's not correct.
I get an error line 5, "no ; before statement", what I don't know what is it.

```
function info2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var cell = '=IMPORTXML("https://example.com&sw=" + sheet.getRange('M:M').getValue() + "&s=On", "/html/body/div[1]/p[2]/a")';
  for (var i in data) {
    for (var j in data[i]) {
      sheet.getRange('O:O').setValue(cell);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita in fact I wrote the error in my last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of test, I realized that my first url was good. The &M2& is increase automatically by googlesheet.

About to get the value against the formula, with the macro of googlesheet, it's easy to get it

```
function val() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O:O').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O:O').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('O1').activate();
};
```

From now, I search to skip the importxml in the cell of the column O when the cell of column O is empty...